# Curvature of $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider $S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ parameterised by $\psi:S^2\to\mathbb{R}^3, (x_1, x_2)\mapsto (x_1,x_2,\sqrt{1-x_1^2-x_2^2})$.

We need to compute the sectional curvature of $S^2$ given this parameterisation. We are told that it suffices to compute this at the point $(0,0,1)$.

So we first obtain the $g_{ij}$ with a view to computing the Christoffel symbols. We found
$g_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1+\frac{x_i^2}{1-x_1^2-x_2^2}, i=j\\ \frac{x_ix_j}{1-x_1^2-x_2^2}, i\neq j\\ \end{cases}$

At the point $(0,0,1)$, $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$, the Kronecker delta. Therefore at this point the Christoffel symbols and therefore the sectional curvature vanish.

My question is: how is it sufficient to compute the sectional curvature at this point if the Christoffel symbols vanish here? Does this not incorrectly imply that the sectional curvature of $S^2$ is 0?

Comment: You asked before (about a day ago) about coordinate vector fields of an embedded manifold but then deleted the question, right ?

Comment: I feel like I've seen this question before just yesterday.

Comment: This is a follow up question to one I asked yesterday. This question is meant to be more precise.

Comment: In the question you deleted, I already told you that the fact that $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ at one point has nothing to do with curvature (neither with Christoffel symbols).

Comment: @Didier thanks for you answer. I’m confused since the Christoffel symbols are computed from the derivatives of g_ij. So at this point the Christoffel symbols vanish. How then do we compute curvature at (0,0,1)? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Also, you should not delete your question once people have answered you. No, the Christoffel symbols do not vanish. The value of a function at one point do not tell anything about its derivatives at that point.

Comment: @Didier Sorry for deleting my question. I wanted to refine it with this question, but I see that it is bad practice.

Comment: @Didier Will the Christoffel symbols not vanish since the derivatives of the Kronecker delta are all 0?

Comment: Try to convince yourself that the equalities $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ at **one point** do not say anything about its derivatives. For example, consider $g_{ij}(x,y) = \delta_{ij} + x$. on a small neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: @Didier Thanks so much, I see my misunderstanding now. What then is the use of considering the $g_{ij}$ at the point (0,0,1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an expression for the metric, you can compute its partial derivatives and evaluate them at $(0,0)$ in order to compute Christoffel symbols and derive the curvature. Hint: you should find $1$.

Your error is saying "since at $(0,0)$, $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$, then all partial derivatives vanish". This is basically an error that is equivalent to saying "all functions $f$ have zero derivative since at $x$, they are constant equal to $f(x)$."

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this and my prior questions

Comment: When I compute the partial derivatives first and then evaluate, I once again get that they vanish.

Comment: @simow That may be true, however the curvature is related to the Chrostoffel symbols and their partial derivatives.